# Output of return statement

Tags: c

Here, not able to understand the nature of return....

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fun1(int i)
{
        return ;
}

int main()
{
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
        {
                printf("%d\n",fun1(i));
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Output:
0
1
2
3
4

Can somebody explain???

Comment: I would highly suggest buying a beginner's book on programming / C. `return` is in no way related to output.

Comment: I don't know about c, but in c++, this program is ill-formed. It should not compile.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag since you are clearly using a C compiler. Your code is invalid if treated as C++.

Comment: Before start coding, determine your program job, what do you want the code to do

Comment: @Mr. Roach: Thanks for your advice. But here it is related to output because return value is the output of my program.

Comment: @David: Sorry, that was my mistake, i accept....;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your program has undefined behaviour. It fails to return values from `fun1`. Anything could happen.

The fact that it compiles at all implies that your compiler adheres to an older standard. For instance C89 says:

> **3.6.6.4 The return statement**
>
> ....
>
> If a return statement without an expression is executed, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

On the other hand C99 says:

> **6.8.6.4 The return statement**
>
> ....
>
> A return statement without an expression shall only appear in a
>   function whose return type is void.

So, if your compiler adheres strictly to C99 or later then your code is invalid.

It's a little pointless reasoning about why the program behaves as it does, since its behaviour is undefined. Perhaps the ABI for this compiler happens to expect the return value to be placed in a register which also contains the value of the caller's loop variable `i` when `fun1` was called. In any case, your program could output anything at all.

Since `fun1` has a return type that it not `void`, you should use the form of the `return` statement that has an expression. For instance:

```
int fun1(int i)
{
    return i;
}
```